# How to boot RedHat Linux in normal mode in VMWare?

Tags: boot, vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux, kickstart

I had an iso image of redhat, into which I placed the kickstart file in the root directory and recreated the iso image. When I tried booting linux from that image (in VMWare) , it started searching for DHCP (boots in network mode).

Can any one tell how to create the iso image with the kickstart file and boot in normal mode?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be caused by two things:

1. Your custom iso image was misconfigured, please check your [kickstart options](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html) for any errors.
2. Your VMware settings were misconfigured, are you able to boot vanilla redhat?

Usually when vmware starts searching for DHCP, you have not mounted the ISO properly.